# Working out the derivative of the log-likelihood for group LASSO

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, regularization, logistic-regression

I'm following the working of the sparse group LASSO in the paper 'A Sparse-Group LASSO' by Simon. For the linear case, we have the problem given as

$$\text{min}_\beta \frac{1}{2}||y-\sum_{l=1}^m X^{(l)}\beta^{(l)}||_2^2 + \text{pen}(\beta).$$

I've omitted the full details of the penalty term, as this question doesn't make use of it. In the paper, the problem is rewritten for logistic regression as

$$\text{min}_\beta \frac{1}{n}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\log(1+\exp(x_i^T \beta))+y_ix_i^T \beta \right)\right] + 
\text{pen}(\beta),$$
although this doesn't show the grouping structure, so my thought was that it should be written as (as is done in 'The group lasso for logistic regression' by Meier, 2008)

$$\text{min}_\beta \frac{1}{n}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\log(1+\exp(\sum_{g=1}^{G}x_{i,g}^T \beta^{(g)}))+y_i \sum_{g=1}^{G} x_{i,g}^T \beta^{(g)} \right)\right] + 
\text{pen}(\beta).$$

Now to my question: In the Simon paper, the details of the logistic implementation aren't given aside from the problem statement. For the linear case, the log-likelihood is rewritten as

$$l(r_{(-k)},\beta) = \frac{1}{2n}||r_{(-k)} - X^{(k)}\beta||_2^2,$$
where $r_{(-k)} = y-\sum_{l\neq k} X^{(l)}\beta^{(l)}$ is the partial residual of $y$, subtracting all group fits other than group $k$. Further, it goes on to show

$$\nabla l(r_{(-k)}, \beta_0) = -X^{(k)\intercal} r_{(-k)}/n.$$

The paper states that for logistic regression, we must find the unpenalised loss function $l(\beta)$ as a function of only $\beta^{(k)}$, with the rest of the coefficients $\beta^{(-k)}$ fixed, so that we define it as $l_k(\beta^{(-k)}, \beta^{(k)}).$

**My question is: How do I find this log-likelihood and derivative in the logistic regression case?**

Comment: The gradient is already weird: it should be (?) $\nabla l(r_{(-k)}, \beta_0) = -X^{(k)\intercal} [r_{(-k)}-X^{(k)}\beta_0]/n$.

Comment: @Steph I couldn't find any mention in the paper, but similar papers have assumed $X$ is orthogonal, which would give the desired gradient I believe.

Comment: even is $X$ is orthogonal, it cannot make the term disappear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write the log-likelihood (to be maximized) as
$$
\phi(\mathbf{b})
=\sum_i 
y_i(c+ \mathbf{x}_{i,k}^T \mathbf{b}) -
\log \left[ 1+\exp(c+\mathbf{x}_{i,k}^T \mathbf{b}) \right]
$$
where $\mathbf{x}_{i,k}$ is the restriction of the predictors from group $k$
in the $i$-th example.
Note that I have a minus sign here?

Simple derivation yields
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{b}}
=
\sum_i 
\left(
y_i
-
\sigma 
\left[
c+\mathbf{x}_{i,k}^T \mathbf{b}
\right]
\right)
\mathbf{x}_{i,k}
$$
using the logistic regression function to model
$p(y=1|\mathbf{x})=\sigma(\mathbf{x}^T\beta)$